# Seeing "modprobe: not found" using nodejs and raspi-io

Tags: node.js, modules

I'm trying to use the johnny-five Node.js framework with raspi-io to do a hello world example based on [this tutorial](http://johnny-five.io/examples/raspi-io/). Here's my code:

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var Raspi = require("raspi-io");
var board = new five.Board({
  io: new Raspi()
});

board.on("ready", function() {
  console.log( "Board ready." );
});
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: modprobe i2c-dev
/bin/sh: 1: modprobe: not found

  at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:1339:13)
  at execSync (child_process.js:1379:13)
  at new I2C (/home/pi/sandbox/node_modules/raspi-io/node_modules/raspi-i2c/lib/index.js:122:5)
  at /home/pi/sandbox/node_modules/raspi-io/lib/index.js:154:16
  at new Raspi (/home/pi/sandbox/node_modules/raspi-io/lib/index.js:189:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/sandbox/button.js:4:7)
  ...
```

I've enabled SPI and I2C in raspi-config, although I'm not sure if that is related. Running `modprobe i2c-dev` confirms that `modprobe` does not exist. Am I missing something? I've also tried reinstalling `module-init-tools`, as suggested in this non-raspi thread: [modprobe not found at all](https://serverfault.com/questions/433195/modprobe-not-found-at-all).

Comment: Which version of the Pi did the tutorial use and which version are you using?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't specify but the illustration shows a Model 2 v1.1 – I'm using a Model A+ V1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modprobe is not in a standard user's path as it is not runnable as a standard user.  It requires superuser privileges to run.

If you use the command sudo modprobe the command will be found.  sudo which modprobe will show its location, normally /sbin/modprobe.

Try launching the script using sudo, i.e. precede the command you use to launch the script with sudo.

Comment: Thank you!  `sudo node example.js` works correctly. Is this common for raspberry pi scripting? I usually avoid executing with sudo (in the web development world) for security reasons.

Comment: It's unavoidable if the script uses commands which require superuser privileges to run (such as modprobe).  In this instance a safer alternative would be to add i2c-dev to /etc/modules so that it will be loaded at boot.

Comment: That makes sense, my scripts don't usually interface with hardware so it's just new to me. Thanks again.